# Can't broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

def qrhouse(A):
    (m,n) = A.shape
    R = A
    V = np.zeros((m,n))
    for k in range(0,min(m-1,n)):
        x = R[k:m,k]
        x.shape = (m-k,1)
        v = x + np.sin(x[0])*np.linalg.norm(x.T)*np.eye(m-k,1)
        V[k:m,k] = v
        R[k:m,k:n] = R[k:m,k:n]-(2*v)*(np.transpose(v)*R[k:m,k:n])/(np.transpose(v)*v)
    R = np.triu(R[0:n,0:n])     
    return V, R

A = np.array( [[1,1,2],[4,3,1],[1,6,6]] )
print qrhouse(A)
```

It's qr factorization code, but I don't know why error happens.
The value error happens in `V[k:m,k] = v`

```
value error :
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

Comment: i have to reshape the V[k:m,k] becuase it's shape is (3) and v's shape is (3,1). But i can't do it..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`V[k:m,k] = v`; `v` has shape (3,1), but the target is (3,). `k:m` is a 3 term slice; `k` is a scalar.

Try using `v.ravel()`.  Or `V[k:m,[k]]`.

But also understand why `v` has its shape.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that would work is `V[k:m,k:k+1] = v`.

`k:k+1` is a 1 term slice, making the target shape (3,1).

This seems like a better solution since you do not have to modify the input array.

Answer (score -1):

Other way to do it is by transpose:

```
V[k:m,k] = v.transpose()
```