# Problem with broadcasting labeling data from generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I am working through the CK+ dataset for facial expression recognition and I'm passing the face images and labels through a `datagen.flow_from_directory` to extract the facial features and map to the labels.

The labels are passed as categorical value and the same range from 0 to 7. The same seem to be passed as one-hot encoded form. My problem is that I can broadcast the label values as one-hot encoded values.

I get the following error:
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,8) into shape (32)`

The code is as follows:

```
import scipy
import os, shutil
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_width, img_height = 224, 224

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 32

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    print(sample_count, 7, 7, 512)
    # Preprocess data - flow_from_directory allows us to extract 
    #... features and labels directly from a directory
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode='categorical')

    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels
```

I get the following shapes:

```
Found 209 images belonging to 8 classes.
Input batch shape:  (32, 224, 224, 3)
Features batch shape:  (32, 7, 7, 512)
Features shape:  (209, 7, 7, 512)
Labels batch shape:  (32, 8)
```

So I am confused as to why the `features_batch` can be broadcasted, but `labels_batch` cannot.

I have tried several things, some include:

1) To flatten the labels array - which doesn't make sense, but just to see and I get the full element count across rows and columns **32*8=259** (as expected).

2) I tried using just `labels[i]=labels_batch`, and `labels=labels_batch` which just returns the last few labels 
**(17, left over from 209-(6*32)=17)**.

3) I also tried to plug another solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824700/cant-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-3-1-into-shape-3). 
By doing:

```
for c in range(0,7):
            labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size, [c]] = labels_batch
```

But instead get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 8)
```

I feel like what I am missing is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. Might anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your labels should be of the shape `labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, num_classes))` instead of `labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))`
and the allocation should of labels from generator should be 
 `labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size,:] = labels_batch`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a something simple with how I was declaring these. Do you per chance have a link with a cheat sheet or refresher content for lists and dictionaries?

Comment: i am not sure, but this seems to be related to numpy indexing and dimensions,i believe the 100 numpy exercises would definitely refresh you https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100/blob/master/100_Numpy_exercises.ipynb