# create new array from other arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a new array from three other arrays so that I want to create a 20x3 array (center_lab) from three 20x1 arrays (TT2r, TT2g, TT2b) so I would get the following:

```
center_lab = np.zeros([20,3])

center_lab[:,0] = TT2r 
center_lab[:,1] = TT2g
center_lab[:,2] = TT2b
```

And I get the next error: could not broadcast input array from shape (21,1) into shape (21,)

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: check array sizes array within the list, must also be the same size.

Comment: The error basically tells you that `[1,2,3]` is not the same as `[[1,2,3]]`

Comment: Your code looks fine, I would recommend printing the shape of each array to make sure it is actually the size you expect `print(center_lab.shape);print(TT2r.shape);print(TT2g.shape);print(TT2b.shape)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39825046/14867730

Comment: Please show [mcve] and full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im not mistaken your `TT2r` arrays have a shape of `(21,1)`

The part of `center_lab` you write into is only of shape `(21,)` since you index the last dimension (as opposed to slicing). If you also remove the last dimensions of your TTs it should fit.

```
center_lab = np.zeros([20,3])

center_lab[:,0] = TT2r[:,0]
center_lab[:,1] = TT2g[:,0]
center_lab[:,2] = TT2b[:,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

*create a 20x3 array (center_lab) from three 20x1 arrays*

This sound like task for `numpy.hstack`, consider following simple example:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
arr2 = np.array([[4],[5],[6]])
arr3 = np.array([[7],[8],[9]])
arr = np.hstack([arr1,arr2,arr3])
print(arr)
```

output

```
[[1 4 7]
 [2 5 8]
 [3 6 9]]
```

Note: I used 3x1 array for sake of clarity. If you would need to stack vertically rather than horizontally as above see `numpy.vstack`.