# could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following python code for QR factorization. At line of `Q[:,i] = u / norm` , I get the error mentioned in the title. Can anyone help, please?

- `Q` is has the shape (3,3),
- `u` is expected to has the shape (3,1)
- `norm` is a scalar

The error message is:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)
```

The expected output is the matrix Q with the shape (3,3).

```py
import numpy as np

def QRfactorization(A):
    # getting the size of the matrix
    N = len(A)

    # preallocating Q 
    Q = np.zeros((N, N))
    
    for i in range(N):
        u =  A[:,i]
        for j in range(i):
            # calculating the projection
            h = np.vdot(u,Q[:,j])
            u = u - h*Q[:,j]
        norm = np.linalg.norm(u) 
        Q[:,i] = u / norm
    #getting R matrix  
    R = Q.T*A
    return Q , R

def main():
    # input is an square matrix A
    A = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
    Q = QRfactorization(A)
    print(Q)

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. It would help if you made a [mre] including the full error message and the expected output. And if you could simplify the code, all the better. For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: @wjandrea For example you could provide us Q.shape, u.shape and norm.shape (if norm is not an integer)

Comment: @wjandrea, Thank you for your comments. I added the information you asked for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824700/cant-broadcast-input-array-from-shape-3-1-into-shape-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of [`numpy.matrix` is discouraged](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), and using `numpy.array` also fixes this issue:

```
def main():
    # input is an square matrix A
    A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
    Q = QRfactorization(A)
    print(Q)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid writing your own and do this directly with `numpy.linalg.qr`

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html

```py
def main():
    # input is an square matrix A
    A = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]])
    q, r = np.linalg.qr(A)
    print(q)
    print(r)
```

**BEWARE**, you are not calculating the R-portion completely/correctly if it matters to your result, as it should be an *upper-triangular matrix*

results with **@Nils Werner**'s `.array()` change to your method
(results are combined into a single array)

```
(array([[ 0.23570226,  0.66666667, -0.23570226],
       [ 0.94280904, -0.33333333, -0.94280904],
       [ 0.23570226,  0.66666667, -0.23570226]]), array([[ 0.23570226,  1.88561808,  0.70710678],
       [ 2.66666667, -1.66666667,  4.        ],
       [-0.23570226, -1.88561808, -0.70710678]]))
```

results from naive `np.linalg.qr` (same for "complete" and "reduced" `mode`s)

```
[[-2.35702260e-01  6.66666667e-01 -7.07106781e-01]
 [-9.42809042e-01 -3.33333333e-01  2.22044605e-16]
 [-2.35702260e-01  6.66666667e-01  7.07106781e-01]]
[[-4.24264069 -5.65685425 -7.07106781]
 [ 0.          1.          2.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.        ]]
```